# $e^{-xy} + e^{xy} = 2e^{-y}$ - where am I going wrong?

Tags: solution-verification

I am trying to see if there is any $x$ (real or complex) for which this equation can be solved.

$$e^{-xy} + e^{xy} = 2e^{-y}$$

Step 1. Multiplying both sides by y,
$$ye^{-xy} + ye^{xy} = 2ye^{-y}$$

Step2. Partially differentiating the original equation (i.e. $e^{-xy} + e^{xy} = 2e^{-y}$ ) w.r.t. x,
$$-ye^{-xy} + ye^{xy} = 0$$

Step3. Adding Steps 1 and 2,
$$2ye^{xy} = 2ye^{-y}$$
this gives $x=-1$.

Obviously this is not a solution. Where am I going wrong? or is there a complex value of x for which Step 3 holds?

Comment: Why can you partially differentiate with respect to $x$ ? For example $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=x^3+x+1$ satisfy $f'(x)=g'(x)$ at $x=0$ but this is not a solution to $f(x)=g(x)$ ?

Comment: Thanks. This explains my mistake! If you post this in the main thread, I will accept it as an answer explaining my mistake.

Comment: You are welcome, I posted it as an answer 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general the solutions of the equations $f'(x)=g'(x)$ and $f(x)=g(x)$ are different.

For example, if $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=x^3+x+1$ for real $x$, then $$f(x)=g(x)\iff x=-1$$ but $$f'(x)=g'(x)\iff x=0.$$

Answer (score 0):

In step 2, when you differentiate with respect to $x$, you will have a factor of $y$.

So, $-y^2e^{-xy}+y^2e^{xy}=0$

Comment: I am not partially differentiating equation in Step 1. I am partially differentiating the *orginal equation* w.r.t. x

Answer (score 0):

The derivative of two different constant functions is zero.  The two functions are not equal.  All equality of derivatives tells you is that the two functions agree up to a constant offset (recall the "${}+C$" from integral calculus).

The partial derivative with respect to $x$ of two different functions depending only on $y$ is zero.  All equality of partial derivatives with respect to $x$ tells you is that the two functions agree up to an arbitrary function in $y$.  Your right-hand side is not "$0$"; it's "$F(y)$", which isn't nearly as convenient for your solution method.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers, but your approach in Step 2 has an error for another reason:

Even if you were looking for an $x$ such that $f(x,y)=g(x,y)$ **for all $y$**, this would hold if you differentiate both sides of this **by $x$** and not **by $y$**.